# If user is part of a group skip

Tags: powershell

Here is code I'm using to add users to two groups based on the company they are part of. Now how can I make it so if the user is already part of the groups it skips that user and moves on to the next one.

```
Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1480"' | %{Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf "HS", "HS Students" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
```

Comment: If the user is part of one of the group, then skip all the groups. Or do you mean that it will just skip that group and then begin to check the next group?

Can you explain it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-ADUser -Filter "-not (memberOf -eq 'CN=MyPermanentGroup,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com') -and -not (memberOf -eq 'CN=MyOtherGroup,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com') -and company -eq '1480'"

Comment: how do you do multiple groups. I need to check to see if they are in HS and HS Students